# Android studio isn't recognizing LG G4

Tags: android, adb, lg

I've got new LG G4 and I've tried all these steps:

*connected my phone with usb.

*installed abd LG G4 driver.

*usb is on PTP mode.

*I've set my G4 to developers mode.

And my Android Studio is still not recognizing my G4. My laptop is recognizing it. I can import photos, music and everything. It is only the android studio which isn't recognizing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the developer options have you set USB debugging on? This might be obvious but you haven't added this information so maybe this might help.

Comment: I can't believe it. When my G4 was connected to the comptuer, the "USB debugging" option didn't appear. When I disconnected my G4 I could see this option and then I set this option on. It works now. thanks alot.